# How to read memory address over ram size in python

Tags: python, c, linux, memory, embedded-linux

I want to read some register from /dev/mem, and here is the sample code

```
import os, sys
fd = os.open("/dev/mem",os.O_RDWR)

#0xFED01004 = 4275048452
os.lseek(fd, 4275048452, os.SEEK_SET)

ret = os.read(fd,2)
print ret

os.close(fd)
print "close"
```

But my ram size is 2 GB(0x7FFFFFFF) and it's less than 4275048452.
It will get bad address error after executing this code.

I usually use memhack tool (write in c ) to do this work, it uses nmap to transform the physical address to virtual address in user space so the tool can read 0xFED01004 correctly. But now I want to use python to do this work.

Can Python achieve that?

If I add ram to 4GB then this code works, but it's not what I want.

Comment: You're trying to read from a physical address though.

Comment: So, what prevents you to use `mmap()` in python? There is a module with the same name IIRC.

Comment: Hi @0andriy, could you give me more information about IIRC? I try to google python IIRC but get nothing. I'm new to Python so that I don't know there is a module in python like nmap() in C.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=iirc